# Underfull hbox in tabular

Tags: tables, line-breaking, warnings

I'm trying to make a table with fixed column widths. Cells in the first column will generally not have enough text to require a line break within the cell. The second column's cells will quite often be multi-line cells. Whenever I have a cell in the first column require a linebreak I get an "underfull \hbox" warning like:

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--7

Here is an example of what I am currently doing:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.25\columnwidth}|p{0.75\columnwidth}|}
    \hline
    longish line of text & second cell that will often have a lot of text\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I don't require that the column widths be fixed to what they are, or fixed at all. I just want to allow newlines in both columns without having the first column get too wide (and cause excessive newlines in the second column). I also need to have this table fit in a twocolumn environment, which is where most of the space restriction comes from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `\raggedright` is acceptable...

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{0.25\columnwidth}|p{0.75\columnwidth}|}
    \hline
\raggedright % PS
    longish line of text & second cell that will often have a lot of text\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

A second version:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{0.25\columnwidth}|p{0.75\columnwidth}|}
    \hline
%\raggedright % PS
    longish line of text & second cell that will often have a lot of text\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

And you'd better add Werner's corrections.

Comment: Thats perfect, I think it even ends up looking better than trying to justify only two words. Is there a better way to get \raggedright for every line than putting it before every row that is a problem?

Comment: You should also use a column specification of the form `|p{\dimexpr0.25\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|p{\dimexpr0.75\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|`

Comment: @Matt You can add \usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{0.25\columnwidth}|p{0.75\columnwidth}|}. Please read also Werner's correction to avoid overfull hboxes.

Comment: Recall that if `\raggedright` is used in the *last* column, the row must be terminated by `\tabularnewline` (or `\arraybackslash` from the `array` package should be used).